# Porting structs to MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how can I port the following Linux declaration to MSVC? "Expected identifier" is what I get as an error.

```
static const struct tap_align_size align_size_000000_00[] = {
    [0] = {.align = 1,.size = 4, },
    [52] = {.align = 1,.size = 4, },
};
```

where

```
struct tap_align_size {
    uint8_t align:4, size:4;
};
```

Comment: This is not standard c++, before c++20. The fact that it works somewhere is just due to a compiler extension, and there's no way to port it to a compiler that doesn't support it.

Comment: I have never seen anything like that. I can guess that this could be a struct packed with 1 byte alignment? can I use something like ```#define PACKED
#pragma pack(push,1)``` ... ```#pragma pack(pop)
#undef PACKED```

Comment: Please include the definition of struct tap_align_size

Comment: added struct definition in the question

Comment: These are C's [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. Very useful info about the size of the array after initialization

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a struct with a constructor (with an array within) or laboriously type `{}` 51 times.  The latter possibility is more risky because you do not know the order of fields in the struct, and even if you knew, a newer version could shuffle them, with the compiler unable to detect the change.

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out. Yes, this is initializer list, I can understand initialization like ```    tap_align_size rt[53];
    rt[0] = { 1,4 };
    rt[52] = { 1,4 };``` but here the array size is not defined. Also forget about alignment, I was confused by "align" member. And later in the code raw memory is mapped in the struct